# Getting E0658 while compiling Rust union of bitfields

Tags: rust, unions, bit-fields, low-level

Trying to use unions and bitfields in Rust, for bitfields I am using the `bitfield` crate, but I have been looking examples of its usage with unions and couldn't find any, now I am getting an error.

Is the right way to solve this error creating a copy constructor for the `Image2D`/`3D types? If so, how to do it?

```
error[E0658]: unions with non-`Copy` fields are unstable
  --> src\main.rs:48:1
   |
48 | / union Image {
49 | |     image3D: Image3D,
50 | |     image2D: Image2D,
51 | | }
   | |_^
   |
   = note: see issue #55149 <https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/55149> for more information

error: aborting due to previous error
```

Here is the implementation of a 2D point:

```
extern crate bitfield;
use bitfield::*;

struct Image2D(u32);
bitfield_bitrange!{struct Image2D(u32)}
impl Image2D{
    bitfield_fields!{
       u32;
       valid, _: 0;
       width, _: 15, 1;
       heigth, _: 29, 16;
       image_type, _:31,30;
    }
}
impl std::fmt::Debug for Image2D {
    bitfield_debug!{
       struct Image2D;
       valid, _: 0;
       width, _: 15, 1;
       heigth, _: 29, 16;
       image_type, _:31,30;
    }
}
```

Comment: You've not really given us enough code to be sure, but I suspect it will be enough to add `#[derived(Copy, Clone)]` to your `Image2D` and `Image3D` structs.

Comment: What part of the error message is unclear to you?

Comment: The problem is that when I added the copy I was trying to add it in the Image class, so it would still complain, if I added it to the 2d or 3d, would still need the clone,but as Michael pointed out, should be both copy and clone for the 2d and 3d image structures! that fixed the issue! 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Per Michael Answer:
Just by deriving the copy and clone into the members of the structure solved the issue:

```
#[derive(Copy,Clone)]
struct Image2D(u32);
bitfield_bitrange!{struct Image2D(u32)}
impl Image2D{
    bitfield_fields!{
       u32;
       valid, _: 0;
       width, _: 15, 1;
       heigth, _: 29, 16;
       image_type, _:31,30;
    }
}
```